# R: Patch a df with smaller df with similar names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 data frames, the second one has a subset of colnales and rownames of the first one:

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
colnames(df1) = c('c1','c2','c3','c4','c5')
rownames(df1) = c('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5')

df2 = as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1, ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
colnames(df2) = c('c2','c3')
rownames(df2) = c('r2','r3')
```

Now I want to patch `df1` with `df2` to get this:

```
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
r1 NA NA NA NA NA
r2 NA  1  1 NA NA
r3 NA  1  1 NA NA
r4 NA NA NA NA NA
r5 NA NA NA NA NA
```

If I use `merge`, colnames order gets mixed up, duplicate rows or columns appear for different `by` options. How do I avoid this? Is there an easy way in R to patch a data frame without changing its structure?

I can only think of a cycle-based solution but I hope there is a one-liner for this.

```
for (i in rownames(df2)){
    for (j in colnames(df2)){
      df1[i,j] = df2[i,j]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Merging data means that you will add up distinct rows. In the cycle-based solution you are _updating_ the data in the frame.

Comment: @ycw That is my desirable output

Comment: @ycw Oh, now I see. I mistyped it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option. Thanks for akrun's suggestion.

```
df1[rownames(df2), colnames(df2)] <- df2
df1
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
r1 NA NA NA NA NA
r2 NA  1  1 NA NA
r3 NA  1  1 NA NA
r4 NA NA NA NA NA
r5 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I guess using `match` instead of `%in%` would be more robust to different orderings across the data.frames.

Comment: I guess `df1[rownames(df2), colnames(df2)] <- 1` should work

Comment: @akrun But that might produce new rows/columns

Comment: @lotrus28 It is giving me the exact same output as in ycw's solution assuming that the example is representative

Comment: @akrun you are right. I will update my answer based on your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun Me neither, but that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that rownames and colnames do not have the same order:

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
colnames(df1) = c('c1','c3','c2','c4','c5')
rownames(df1) = c('r1','r3','r2','r4','r5')

df2 = as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
colnames(df2) = c('c2','c3')
rownames(df2) = c('r2','r3')
```

Then the code below seems to refer to correct columns and rows:

```
> df1
   c1 c3 c2 c4 c5
r1 NA NA NA NA NA
r3 NA NA NA NA NA
r2 NA NA NA NA NA
r4 NA NA NA NA NA
r5 NA NA NA NA NA
> df2
   c2 c3
r2  1  3
r3  2  4
> df1[rownames(df2),colnames(df2)] <- df2
> df1
   c1 c3 c2 c4 c5
r1 NA NA NA NA NA
r3 NA  4  2 NA NA
r2 NA  3  1 NA NA
r4 NA NA NA NA NA
r5 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I did not notice that the accepted answer was edited. Originally it was not accurate. This example shows explicitly how different column and row name order is taken into account.

Comment: @Heikki Thanks for your answer. Yes, after akrun's suggestion I updated my answer. I am going to give you an upvote because you provided a nice example when column and row names are not in order.